# Stripe Checkout with Rails Charging Different Amounts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, token, payment, stripe-payments

I am following Stripe's rails guide to set up a basic checkout. I got it to work, but only for one amount of $5.

Having trouble finding documentation on adding another amount. I want one page to have a $5, $10 and $15 checkout option (i am creating a donate page).

I know I can create multiple controllers for each payment amount but that seems a bit overboard. Any suggestions would be more than appreciated. Here is my code so far...

charges_controller.rb:

```
class ChargesController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    # Amount in cents
    @amount = 500

    customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
      :email => 'example@stripe.com',
      :card  => params[:stripeToken]
    )

    charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
      :customer    => customer.id,
      :amount      => @amount,
      :description => 'Rails Stripe customer',
      :currency    => 'usd'
    )

  rescue Stripe::CardError => e
    flash[:error] = e.message
    redirect_to charges_path
  end
end
```

new.html.erb (charge view page):

```
<%= form_tag charges_path do %>
  <article>
    <label class="amount">
      <span>Amount: $5.00</span>
    </label>
  </article>

  <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
      data-key="<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>"
      data-description="A month's subscription"
      data-amount="500"></script>
<% end %>
```

charges.html.erb (layouts):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <%= yield %>
</body>
</html>
```

stripe.rb (initializer):

```
Rails.configuration.stripe = {
  :publishable_key => ENV['PUBLISHABLE_KEY'],
  :secret_key      => ENV['SECRET_KEY']
}

Stripe.api_key = Rails.configuration.stripe[:secret_key]
```

routes.rb:

```
resources :charges
```

Thank you! Still new to rails so I'm guessing this is something simple.

Comment: you need to send the amount from view and in controller multiply that by 100 to convert into cents and then pass that to stripe and done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add some radio buttons to your form with different amounts and remove the `data-amount` from the script then it will use the `amount` value from your form. Something like:

```
<% ["500", "1000", "1500"].each do |amount| %>
  <input type="radio" name="amount" value="<%= amount %>" />
<% end %>
```

Obviously you'll want to spruce that up a bit with labels and maybe a default selection but that approach will let you get a choice of amount from the user.

Then, in your controller you will need to create your charge with the passed in amount rather than `@amount`:

```
charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
  :customer    => customer.id,
  :amount      => params[:amount],
  :description => 'Rails Stripe customer',
  :currency    => 'usd'
)
```

Comment: But he is using a `form_tag` so he needs a lot of changes I think. He needs to make a `form_for` or use something to send the amount to the controller.

Comment: Realised I'd missed the controller code change off. All you need to do is use `params[:amount]` in the call to create the charge.